# Is there a way in drools fusion to match events that are oldest first?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I have a stream of events, let's call them `Foo`, which are inserted in time order, and I have another stream of events `Bar` which are also inserted in time order.

I have a rule, which does a fuzzy match of `Bar`s to `Foo`s, and what I would like to do is to mach the oldest `Bar` with the oldest `Foo`, is there a way to ensure that the rule is triggered in time order of events - kind of like `salience` but for time..

`Foo`s arrive at a faster rate than `Bar`s, and not every `Foo` will have a `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to match the oldest `Foo` with the oldest `Bar`, you can try something like this:

```
rule "Oldest Far with oldest Bar"
when
  $oldestF: Foo()
  not Foo( this before $oldestF )
  $oldestB: Bar(//in here you can correlate this Bar with the $oldestF)
  not Bar( this before $oldestBar)
then
  //do something
end
```

If you want to process these matches in order, then you may want to use a flag in your facts so they can be discarded once processed continuing with the cycle:

```
rule "Oldest Far with oldest Bar"
when
  $oldestF: Foo( processed == false )
  not Foo( this before $oldestF )
  $oldestB: Bar( processed == false //in here you can correlate this Bar with the $oldestF)
  not Bar( this before $oldestBar)
then
  //do something
  modify($oldestF){ setProcessed(true) };
  modify($oldestB){ setProcessed(true) };
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Ahh - the `not Foo( this before $oldestF)` that's the trick I missed!